# Crear un login que empiece por números con Transact-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy haciendo una página con php y un SGBD SQL Server. Estoy organizando los logins de los clientes por su DNI, el problema viene cuando intento crear un login mediante Transact SQL, la base de datos no detecta los números del DNI y me salta un error.

[image: error]

Si cambio el nombre si funciona:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

/****************************************************************/
He encontrado la solución justo antes de enviar la pregunta, aún así, la voy a subir respondida por si a alguien le pasa lo mismo. Un saludo

Comment: Esto parece que puede llegar a ser un serio problema al momento de administrar tantos logins y usuarios. Sin embargo, no tengo información suficiente como para dar alguna alternativa y deseo que no tengas muchos problemas.

Comment: Tengo pensado administrarlo todo desde la página web, para poder borrar los logins (con sus respectivos usuarios) en 2 clics. Gracias por preocuparte, un saludo. @LuisCazares

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si se ponen Corchetes te funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]